# Programmatically add a POST method to AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, boto3

I am trying to programmatically create a POST method from an AWS API gateway which invokes a lambda function. However I don't know how to do this. This is what I have tried:

```
 response = client.create_rest_api(
name=api_name,
endpointConfiguration={
    'types': [
        'REGIONAL',
    ],

},
)
```

This creates the API.

```
 response = client.put_method(
restApiId=api_id,
resourceId=func_arn,
httpMethod='POST',
authorizationType='NONE',
)
```

I am putting the API string ID (not the name) and am passing the lambda ARN. However, I am getting the error:

```
 botocore.errorfactory.NotFoundException: An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the CreateResource operation: Invalid Resource identifier specified
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help in getting the API POST method to invoke the lambda would be appreciated.

Comment: rather than using aws-sdk, try aws-cdk, it provides constructs which creates cloudformation to create necessary resources. will be super easy. for you error, you need to create a resource before creating methods.  `resourceId` is not func_arn it should be the id resource we create. Once method is created, we then need to create integration which accepts your func_arn

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted it seems that you want to use **incorrect** `resourceId`. It appearts you are using lambda function arn (`func_arn`). However, `resourceId` should be a resource created by [create_resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_resource) method.

So once you create your resource using `create_resource`, then you can add a method to this resource using `put_method`.

Comment: I need to perform the put integration to have my API invoke the lambda the function is `api_client.put_integration(rest_api_id, resource_id, httpMethod, type, uri, integration_method_type) `. However, when I use the arn for the uri parameter, I am getting an error, what is the uri I should use?